# Restrict concurrent viewing of a document

Tags: permissions

Due to copyright restrictions we have documents that may only be read by a single person at any given time. Is it possible to prevent concurrent viewing of a document in SharePoint and how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not OOTB (Out Of The Box),
SharePoint is just a WebServer serving content, so anyone who has bookmarked a URL can get to the content.

You would have to add code to make the content unavailable,
(move it to another *secret* URI, or change rights) once it is served.
Feasible to program for anyone with decent SharePoint knowledge.

But your biggest challenge is making the document available again.

The user can turn of the browser...
The connection can break...
...
...

Loads of scenarios to deal with

---

Less secure is hiding from other users,
Takes some CSR-Client Side Rendering code and a Workflow

- Create a metadata column: Being read by:
- Display all files with empty values
- Change the Open link with CSR to execute a Workflow

  - set the metadata column to the current user
- The CSR script checks if the document is being read by someone else

  - If so, they bypassed your proces somehow..
    You could redirect them to a You are fired video
- now the CSR script opens the document as an IFRAME in a `reading.aspx` page  with a shitload of (mainly dummy) URL parameters
  This way you can create a URI so bookmarking/illegal access can be caught,
  note that anyone with Web knowledge can still find the correct document URI
- create a View whos is viewing Which document, exclude the open Link
  (also put this ListView on the `reading.aspx` page)

If your PWC auditors are as IT ignorant as many are,
it will pass the test